# Методы обновления WebView

Tags: java, android

Во фрагменте использую `WebView` .

Необходимо создать отдельный метод, который бы реализовывал обновление страницы в `WebView` и мог быть вызван из другого класса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С такой постановкой вопроса могу посоветовать только такое, весьма очевидное решение:

```
WebView mWebView;
...

public void reloadWebView() {
    mWebView.reload();
}
```

Comment: вот вот я тоже подумывал об этом  но почемуто все водин голос говорят этот метод использовать нежелатеьно

Comment: @elik, Можно еще вот так: `mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload(true)");`.

Comment: а между ними принципиальная разница есть?)или на любителя?

Comment: @elik, Если для загрузки страницы Вы используете метод `mWebView.postUrl()`, то `mWebView.reload()` не сработает корректно.

Comment: поняяятно )спасибо )